# Concurrent updates handling in ASP.NET or SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

There is a table called `Accounts` that looks like this:

```
AccountID   AccountName   AccountTotalMoney
-------------------------------------------
  1           Steven           600
  3           Scott            800
```

But users can updates the row record at the same time like below now:

```
User A:UPDATE Accounts SET AccountTotalMoney=700 WHERE AccountID=1;
User B:UPDATE Accounts SET AccountTotalMoney=900 WHERE AccountID=1;
User C:UPDATE Accounts SET AccountTotalMoney=1000 WHERE AccountID=1;
.
.
.
```

So I would like to prevent multiple users updating the same record at the same time .
Just one after another.

I am a newbie in this aspect. Sorry for my bad english. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of possibilities.

[opinion: i think most web application do optimistic concurrency handling]:

A good tutorial on optimistic concurrency handling is found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404102.aspx

Small abstract:

Similarly, when two users are visiting a page, one user might be in the midst of updating a record when it is deleted by another user. Or, between when a user loads a page and when they click the Delete button, another user might have modified the contents of that record.

There are three concurrency-control strategies available:

- Do nothing—If concurrent users are modifying the same record, let the last commit win (the default behavior).
  •
- Optimistic concurrency—Assume that while there might be concurrency conflicts every now and then, the vast majority of the time such conflicts won't arise; therefore, if a conflict does arise, just inform the user that their changes can't be saved, because another user has modified the same data.
- Pessimistic concurrency—Assume that concurrency conflicts are commonplace and that users won't tolerate being told their changes weren't saved because of another user's concurrent activity; therefore, when one user starts updating a record, lock it, thereby preventing any other users from editing or deleting that record until the user commits their modifications.

Answer (score 5):

I think Pleuns answer is good. To be more concrete:

- Optimistic concurrencey - Check that the row hasnt changed and do a rollback if it did. Example: add a version column that is increased after each update and check that the version number is the same when you do the update.
- Pessimistic concurrency: More complicated. Use the transactionlevel IsolationLevel.Serializable to lock the row, but this is not a good idea when the transaction spans over several web requests.